# Multiple column pandas vectorized string function?

Tags: python, string, numpy, pandas, vectorization

Is there a way of querying a DataFrame for rows that contain a certain string in any column? Something like `Series.str` except for a DataFrame? Here's what I have so far:

```
In [2]: s = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est"

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(s.split(' ')).reshape((-1, 4)), columns=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
           one            two         three        four
0        Lorem          ipsum         dolor         sit
1        amet,    consectetur   adipisicing       elit,
2          sed             do       eiusmod      tempor
3   incididunt             ut        labore          et
4       dolore          magna       aliqua.          Ut
5         enim             ad         minim     veniam,
6         quis        nostrud  exercitation     ullamco
7      laboris           nisi            ut     aliquip
8           ex             ea       commodo  consequat.
9         Duis           aute         irure       dolor
10          in  reprehenderit            in   voluptate
11       velit           esse        cillum      dolore
12          eu         fugiat         nulla   pariatur.
13   Excepteur           sint      occaecat   cupidatat
14         non      proident,          sunt          in
15       culpa            qui       officia    deserunt
16      mollit           anim            id         est

[17 rows x 4 columns]

In [5]: mask = df['one'].str.contains('dolor') | df['two'].str.contains('dolor') | df['three'].str.contains('dolor') | df['four'].str.contains('dolor')

In [6]: df[mask]
Out[6]: 
       one    two    three    four
0    Lorem  ipsum    dolor     sit
4   dolore  magna  aliqua.      Ut
9     Duis   aute    irure   dolor
11   velit   esse   cillum  dolore

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

Ideally, I would like to replace the last two lines with something similar to this:

```
df[df.ix[:, 'one':'four'].str.contains('dolor')]
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas does not have DataFrame.str methods (at least not yet).
However, you could use

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.logical_or.reduce(
    [df[col].str.contains('dolor') 
     for col in df.loc[:, 'one':'four'].columns])
```

This is a little less writing, and a bit quicker than

```
mask = df['one'].str.contains('dolor') | df['two'].str.contains('dolor') | df['three'].str.contains('dolor') | df['four'].str.contains('dolor')
```

---

```
In [29]: %timeit mask = np.logical_or.reduce([df[col].str.contains('dolor') for col in df.loc[:, 'one':'four'].columns]); df[mask]
1000 loops, best of 3: 761 µs per loop

In [30]: %timeit mask = df['one'].str.contains('dolor') | df['two'].str.contains('dolor') | df['three'].str.contains('dolor') | df['four'].str.contains('dolor'); df[mask]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the vectorized operations of a `pd.np.char.array()`:

```
a = pd.np.char.array(df.values)
mask = a.find('dolor')!=-1
df2 = df.iloc[np.any(mask, axis=1)]
```

and the content of `df2` will be:

```
       one    two    three    four
0    Lorem  ipsum    dolor     sit
4   dolore  magna  aliqua.      Ut
9     Duis   aute    irure   dolor
11   velit   esse   cillum  dolore
```

Comment: this is definetely the fastest solution: 1000 loops, best of 3: 358 µs per loop

Comment: note that this will choke on Nan's (this is the reason pandas exposes the str ops, so that they will work with missing values)

Answer (score 0):

this will give you information if theres 'dolor' in any of the columns:

```
df.ix[:, 'one':'four'].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('dolor'), axis=1)
```

will give you true/false value for each row of any of the columns

if you combine this with another apply, you'll get info for the total columns

```
df.ix[:, 'one':'four'].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('dolor'), axis=1).apply(lambda x: True in x.values, axis=1)
```

and using this as the column mask will give your result:

```
df[df.ix[:, 'one':'four'].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('dolor'), axis=1).apply(lambda x: True in x.values, axis=1)]
```

however this is about 3-4 times slower :( that unutbu solutions.